# How can I make a resizable array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, implementation, resizable

What is the best way to do a resizable array in Java? I tried using Vector, but that shifts all elements over by when when you do an insert, and I need an array that can grow but the elements stay in place. I'm sure there's a simple answer for this, but I still not quite sure.

Comment: An array is a static datastructure, so they can't grow. You need to use an dynamic datastructure for this. LinkedList is common, as Alex suggested.

Comment: don't use Arrays, use a List implementation that is tuned for what you need to be doing. If you only append the ArrayList is good, if you need to insert and delete in the middle or head then LinkedLists are good. Say away from raw Arrays as well as Vector and Hashtable they are old crusty and for all intents and purposes deprecated

Comment: You might still want arrays in java if you don't want boxing to occur for every operation.

Comment: What **exactly** do expect as a result, when you insert the value `X` into the array `[1, 2, 3]` at position 1? How should that work *without* shifting some values to the right?

Answer (score 24):

As an alternative, you could use an [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It is a resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

Usage (using String):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("a");
myList.add("c");
myList.add("b");
```

The order will be just like you put them in: a, c, b.

You can also get an individual item like this:

```
String myString = myList.get(0);
```

Which will give you the 0th element: "a".

Comment: You'd have to `import java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @isbadawi No, I wrote my original answer while writing C# and did some weird mix of the 2. I edited it.

Comment: Note that auto-boxing is happening when you add the ints to the List (since java doesn't support primitives in generics)

Comment: Is there a difference between this and the `util.LinkedList`?

Comment: It will give you the 1st element of the list, there is no "0th". (+1, of course, good answer.)

Answer (score 5):

Like Sanjo pointed out: "`An array is a static datastructure, so they can't grow`". The list interface can by backed by an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array#In_computer_science)(for example [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) like Kevin pointed out in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581972/how-can-i-make-a-resizable-array-in-java/2581979#2581979)). When the list structure is full and a new item has to be added to the list. Then the structure first creates a new array which can contain the old elements plus the new element which has to be added to the list.

The list interface has a different implementations which all have there pros/cons and you should pick the one best solving your problem-set. Below I will try to give a short summary when to use which implementation:

### Not thread-safe implementations:

- [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. You should use this implementation when you are doing a lot of `size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator` operations run in constant time. The `add` operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. I think you should use this implementation when doing more lookups(`get()`) then adding items to list(`add()`).
- [LinkedList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): This implementation is not backup by an array but "links" the nodes together. In my opinion you should use this implementation when you are doing more `add()` then `get()`.

### Thread-safe implementations:

Be aware that these list implementations aren't [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29)-safe which means it is possible to get [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition.) when accesing them from multiple threads. If you want to use List implementations from multiple threads I would advise you to study the [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package and use implementation from that class.

Comment: Be *very* wary of using LinkedList. Although adding an item requires only O(1) complexity, getting the nth index is on the order of O(n) complexity. Even in  circumstances where most of the operations on the array are appending new items, LinkedList can still sometimes be a lot slower than other alternatives. That being said, when LinkedList is used properly, the performance gains can be astronomical.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should use ArrayList instead of Vector for reasons explained in other answers.

However ...

> I tried using Vector, but that shifts all elements over by when when you do an insert, and I need an array that can grow but the elements stay in place.

When you do an `insertElementAt(pos, elem)`, you have *specifically asked for* the element shifting.  If you don't want the elements to be shifted, you should use `set(pos, elem)` instead.  Or if you want to add the element at the end of the vector, you can also use `add(elem)`.

Incidentally, the previous paragraph applies to all implementations of `List`, not just `Vector`, though the implementation details and performance vary across the different kinds of `List`.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using Vector, but that shifts all elements over by when when you do an insert, and I need an array that can grow but the elements stay in place.

You probably want to use ArrayList instead of Vector.

They both provide about the same interface, and you can replace elements with both of them by calling `set(idx, element)`. That does not do any shifting around. It also does not allow you to grow the array, though: You can only insert at already occupied positions (not beyond the current size of the array), to add new elements at the end you have to use `add(element)`.

The difference between ArrayList and Vector is that Vector has synchronization code which you most likely do not need, which makes ArrayList a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to operate array data after all element had already inserted or deleted, there is a way that try to create a LinkedList or ArrayList, its simply resize, after the data input is finished, you can transfer the ArrayList to an Array, then do all the things you normally to Array.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList and LinkedList

**Space Complexity:**

a) ArrayList:
Allocates a chunk of memory when you initialize and doubles everytime it reaches it max size whenever you add an element dynamically.

b) LinkedList:
It allocates memory only everytime you add an item to the list.

**Runtime Complexity:**

a) ArrayList:
Search is faster, insertion and deletion is slower compared to linked list

b) LinkedList:
Insertion and deletion is faster, search is slower compared to array list

Comment: Also note that LinkedList takes up a lot more memory and, if overused, can sometimes result in horrendous memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

An array cannot be resized dynamically in Java. The solution to this is using ArrayList or creating another temporary array and then assign it.

You can find tutorials about ArrayList, but if you just want custom ResizableArray in Java. Here's it is. But it's NOT recommend to use! It's just a FAKE resizable array and heap memory will be increased when you create too many objects. This is just to show you the idea.

- The Interface

```
public interface Resizable<T> {

    void add(T data);
    int delete(int index);
    int size();
    void print();
}
```

- Implementation Class

```
public class ResizeableImpl<T> implements Resizable<T> {

    private Object[] temp = null;
    private Object[] originals = new Object[0];

    @Override
    public void add(T data) {
        Object[] temp = new Object[originals.length+1];
        for (int i=0; i<originals.length; i++) {
            temp[i]=originals[i];
        }
        temp[originals.length]=data;
        originals=temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(int index) {
        int success=0;
        switch (originals.length) {
            case 0: //No Data to delete
                success=0;
                break;
            case 1: //One Data is delete and so no data, too!
                originals = new Object[0];
                success = 1;
                break;
            default: //>=2
                int count=0;
                originals[index]=null;
                temp = new Object[originals.length-1];
                for (int i=0; i<originals.length; i++) {
                    if (originals[i]!=null)
                    temp[count++]=originals[i];
                }
                originals = temp;
                success = 1;
        }

        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return originals.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        if (originals.length==0) {
            System.out.println("No data available!");
            return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<originals.length; i++) {
            if (sb==null) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(originals[i]);
            }
            else {
                sb.append(", "+originals[i]);
            }
        }
        sb.append(".");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- Main method

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Program to interfaces, not implementations
        Resizable<Integer> obj = new ResizeableImpl<>();

        obj.add(13);
        obj.add(20);
        obj.add(17);
        obj.add(25);
        obj.add(100);
        obj.add(12);
        obj.print();

        int result = obj.delete(2); //This will delete 17.
        if (result==1) {
            System.out.println("Deletion is successful!");
        }
        obj.print();

        obj.delete(3); //This will delete 100.
        obj.print();
    }
}
```

Output

```
13, 20, 17, 25, 100, 12.
Deletion is successful!
13, 20, 25, 100, 12.
13, 20, 25, 12.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either ArrayList or LinkedList.

Answer (score -2):

Using wonderful classes in Collections framework is the better than using arrays.
But in case your question is from a "quizzing" perspective, here is what you should do.
Create your own resize method such as:

```
  int[] oldArray = {1,2,3};

  int oldSize = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(oldArray);
  Class elementType = oldArray.getClass().getComponentType();
  Object newArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
         elementType,newSize);
  int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize,newSize);
  if (preserveLength > 0)
      System.arraycopy (oldArray,0,newArray,0,preserveLength);

  oldArray = newArray;
```

Comment: This does not resize the array. It creates a new array. Which means none of the objects that hold a reference to the old array will be see the changes.

Comment: Guilty as charged; please disregard my answer above.

Comment: If we should disregard your answer maybe you could just delete it all together? Then you will also not risk getting downvoted again?

Comment: I did not downvote you ;). I am against down-voting myself unless a answer/question is totally useless.